# How can I split this data into 4 separate fields?

Tags: python

I have a data file that contains a date and the average price of gas for that date. I want to be able to read the data from a file, store that data in a list named "gasList", and then split that data in the list into 4 separate fields so that I can display each field separately.

Here is the date followed by the price of gas:

```
04-05-1993:1.068
```

I want to break this data down into these four separate fields:

```
04 05 1993 1.068?
```

I want to be able to test it like this:

```
>>>print(gasList[0])
04
>>>print(gasList[2])
1993
>>>print(gasList[3])
1.068
```

Comment: Can you share some example code that you've tried? I'd also suggest to search for `re` the regular-expression package.

Comment: can you include more than 1 line of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want is `list.split`. In this case, the code would look like this:

```py
data = "04-05-1993:1.068"
new_data = data.replace(":", "-").split("-")
```

This sets `new_data` to be a list of 4 different strings, which are only the significant parts.